# Make a absolute positioned div same height as parent (not relative)

Tags: css

I want to have a div in the background (100% width of browser) by mouseover on a content-div. Everything works great but i dont know is there a solution to make the background div as height as the parent? 
Without using Jquery? Pure CSS would be great!
Thanks!

```css
.content {
  /*  position: relative;  >> will make the absoluted positioned div 100%width of the browser*/
  z-index: 1;
}
.background {
  position: absolute;
  background: aqua;
  width: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}
.post:hover .background {
  display: block;
  height: 10%;
  /* WHAT TO DO? */
}
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="background"></div>
    …content…
  </div>
</div>
```

part of the problem is: the "post" div is in a centerd "main" div with a given width and i want to have a background-div that has 100% width of the viewport

Sorry, it is a bit hard to explain what i need, therefore I make a small sketch here:

[image]

[image]

Comment: this will make the div width / height 100% of the viewport

Comment: Can you rephrase your question then, I don't quite understand what you intend to accomplish

Comment: @ctwheels I'm afraid that needs relative as well

Answer (score 0):

This is posible with vw units, look:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.main {
  background: #29D;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}
.post {
  background: #E31;
  margin: 3vw 3vw 3vw 12vw;
}
.content {
  background: #8D5;
  margin: 2vw;
}
.content img {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: -14vw;
  display: block;
}
@media(min-width: 800px) {
  .content img {
    margin-left: calc(800px / 2 - 50vw - 14vw);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  .main
  <div class="post">
    .post

    <div class="content">
      .content
      <img src="http://s3.postimg.org/3k8v5p0v7/dragon.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      .content
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      .content
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

First thing you need to know is the max width of your wrapper. In my case it is 800px. You have to **substitute all the 800's** with your size. Then notice that all your left margins should be in vw units or pixels but not 100%. **The trick here is that calc() function and the media query!**

Comment: thanks for this, but I dont see at the moment how this will help me, i added a sketch to my first post to show what i need. All the best!

Comment: you want it to have parent's height and viewport's width, is that right? I may give you a css only answer but I'd need to use relative and change html a little bit. What do you think?

Comment: yes i want it to have parent's height and viewport width, thats right. Do you think that is possible with css only?